# Where can I put seed code using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I created an ASP.NET Core web application using the Visual Studio wizard, which generated all the DbContext stuff. I am currently trying to implement the [Enum Lookup Table Generator package](https://github.com/timabell/ef-enum-to-lookup). The documentation says:

> Run `EnumToLookup.Apply()` from your Seed method in either your
>   database initializer or your EF Migrations.

My issue is that my DbContext does not currently use a database initializer.

Where should I run `EnumToLookup.Apply()`? Do I *need* to add a database initializer so that I can override the `Seed()` method where the documentation says to put `EnumToLookup.Apply()`?

My DbContext looks like this:

```
namespace WebApplication3.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        public DbSet<WebApplication3.Models.Restaurant> Restaurant { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WebApplication3.Models.Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That package is for EF6, are you sure it's going to work in EF Core?

Comment: I’m not positive. Is IDatabaseInitializer used in Core?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Also, the SQL generated is vastly different in many cases so it might not be compatible at the lowest level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research and it turns out that while EF6 had the ability to add seed data, EF7 / EF Core 2.0 **does not include this ability**.

[This functionality may be added with the release of EF Core 2.1, but it might not make it in.](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/629)

Comment: [Data seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) will be added in EF Core 2.1. Migrations has supported Insert, Update, and Delete operations since verstion 2.0.

Comment: @bricelam  Thanks for the info!